# Помогите с регулярными выражениями RewriteRule (htaccess)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Здравствуйте,

Нужно сделать редирект для категорий, например:

`https://mysite.ru/123-cats` на `https://mysite.ru/shop/cats`

и со страницы товара, например:

`https://mysite.ru/cats/834-whiskas.html` на `https://mysite.ru/product/whiskas`

Подскажите как будет выглядить RewriteRule для этих двух правил

Comment: а 123 и 834 это что?

Comment: @Naumov, некий префикс из чисел (id товара или категории), они не меняются, но могут быть двухзначные и трехзначные.

Comment: на чём написан движок? думаю вам придёться делать это через него, так как минимум надо вычислить id категории или id товара.

Comment: Переношу с Prestashop на Wordpress. Да, я уже задумался про встроенную в него маршрутизацию...

Answer (score 0):

Получилось решить проблему. Во-первых, нужно было обратить внимание, что у Wordpress используется RewriteBase, а во-вторых важен порядок RewriteRule. Вот это то, что мне нужно было:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/product [NC]  # если не начинается с /product
RewriteRule ^.*/\d+-(.+)\.html$ /product/$1 [R=301,L] # товар
RewriteRule ^\d+-(.+)$ /shop/$1 [R=301,L] # категория
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Это нужно было для перехода с Prestashop на Wordpress, чтобы сохранить старые ссылки.